# New instance with same @@VERSION as existing instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, instance, setup

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 server with several instances installed. Is there a way to add a new instance and have it be to the same build as the existing (and updated / patched) instances?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is no magic "be like that guy" feature. What you have to do is either:

1. install RTM and then apply the SP + CU; or
2. slipstream the same SP + CU into the RTM binaries and install that. [These instructions are applicable to both SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/petersad/create-a-merged-slipstream-drop-containing-sql-server-2008-server-pack-1-and-a-cumulative-update-cu-based-on-server-pack-1), though the process is a little easier in SQL Server 2012.

The former is easier but could require more downtime.